# Script is not working in WebView in UWP

Tags: c#, facebook, webview, uwp

I am using following web view in xaml.

```
<WebView x:Name="FBCommentsTest"></WebView>
```

And i am trying to embed HTML data to that web view in the following way in the c# end.

```
FBCommentsTest.NavigateToString("<html><head></head><body><div id=\"fb-root\"></div><div id=\"fb-root\"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) return;js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;js.src = \"http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=" + APP_KEY + "\";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script><div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\""
                + mExternalUrl + "\" data-width=\"500\"></div> </body></html>");
```

But, in the web view i am getting an empty screen not able to get the facebook comments view.
How to enable the script in web view in uwp.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: try to add NavigationFailed event to webview to check is there some exception

Comment: Hi @AlexejSommer i am not getting any exception, but web view is empty.

Comment: Coudn't check it because don't know APP_KEY and mExternalUrl variables values. May be you can create some test app to show keys for public. When you run this page in usual browser do you get something? There is might be some js exception..

Comment: Please check with the following values. APP_KEY=1458592010850829 and mExternalUrl="http://www.maalaimalar.com/News/TopNews/2016/08/09144120/1031630/Fantastic-Job-Enjoyed-Every-Minute-Raghuram-Rajan.vpf"

Comment: I can't see anything inside browsers. And webview is like browser. Check your js code

Answer (score 1):

> But, in the web view i am getting an empty screen not able to get the facebook comments view. How to enable the script in web view in uwp.

The `NavigateToString`method does not provide a way to generate or provide css, scripts, images, and fonts resources programmatically. You can refer to [WebView.NavigateToString method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetostring.aspx).

You can transfer your string into HTML file, and use `Navigate` method to navigate to the HTML page. Just for example, create a HTMLPage file in the project and code for it, then in the c# code behind:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///HTMLPage1.html");
FBCommentsTest.Navigate(uri);
```

Comment: @BhanuprakashMankala, OK, your content of html depend on the script function, looks like there is some other package installed in your project, so I can't test that, but if your html code is right, it should work. Look forward to your effort.

Comment: @BhanuprakashMankala, any new results? any problem?

Comment: Hi @grace, it has been moved into low priority for now. So, i have not anything. Any concerns i will let you know.

Comment: It is incorrect that NavigateToString does not provide a way to provide scripts: " NavigateToString provides an easy way to navigate to static HTML content, including content with references to resources such as CSS, scripts, images, and fonts." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetolocalstreamuri?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_NavigateToLocalStreamUri_Windows_Foundation_Uri_Windows_Web_IUriToStreamResolver_